# redux action, dispatch object with arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I came across below codes

```
const ERROR_MSG = 'ERROR_MSG'

function errorMsg(msg){
    return { msg, type:ERROR_MSG }
}

export function register({user,pwd,type}){

    return dispatch=>{
        axios.post('/user/register', {user,pwd,type})
            .then(res=>{
                if(res.status!==200){
                    dispatch(errorMsg(res.data.msg))
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Its dispatch recieve a function as param, and the param return something. I'm not so comfortable with it, why need to create extra function? It make sense if errorMsg is global or else it will have redundant functions.

is it possible if I use arrow function then dispatch the action object straight away in the callback?

`dispatch(()=>{res.data.msg, type:ERROR_MSG})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but note that your arrow function is not returning anything:

```
dispatch(()=>{res.data.msg, type:ERROR_MSG})
```

Either use an explicit return:

```
dispatch(()=>{return {res.data.msg, type:ERROR_MSG}})
```

Or wrap it with an expression:

```
dispatch(()=> ({res.data.msg, type:ERROR_MSG}))
```

Or just pass the object directly to dispatch:

```
dispatch({msg: res.data.msg, type:ERROR_MSG})
```

Comment: or I can simply dispatch like this? `dispatch({ msg: res.data.msg, type:ERROR_MSG })`

Comment: yeah i just added that to the answer

Comment: well i include them to show the OP where he went wrong with the arrow function that wasn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible to dispatch straight away with arrow function however its not actually required, Instead of calling an extra function in `dispatch`, you could just dispatch the action with an object

```
return dispatch=>{
    axios.post('/user/register', {user,pwd,type})
        .then(res=>{
            if(res.status!==200){
                dispatch({ msg: res.data.msg, type:ERROR_MSG })
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: is this required redux-thunk?

Comment: yes, action creators needs to return plain objects, however using custom middlewares like redux-thunk you could have async action creators as well

Comment: why redux by default don't handle async action? seems like redux thunk is a must, hmm.

Comment: Yes redux by default doesn't handle async actions, redux-thunk or redux-saga are the options available

Comment: your answer ignores the real problem the OP was facing (an arrow function that wasn't returning anything). It is implied that you are saying the use of an arrow function in this case is wrong and can't be done, which is false.

Comment: I didn't say that an arrow function can't be used in the dispatch but its really unnecessary when you just want to return an object

Comment: I think you should read the original question again: "_is it possible if I use arrow function then dispatch the action object straight away in the callback?_" - The OP asked about returning the object via the arrow function but gave a wrong implementation (didn't return anything). your answer is: "_yes, Instead of calling an extra function in dispatch, you could just dispatch the action with an object_". Although you are right, that doesn't address the wrong code the OP posted and can confuse the OP and other readers on how to use arrow functions.